# Windows 11 - Never Combine taskbar buttons BUT also hide labels (so only small icons left)

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

After the recent windows 11 updates a few months ago, my Never Combine option went away, but then after the most recent update, it came back.
I see the Never option below:
[image]

But it shows Labels, I'd rather just Never combine, but only show the icons so that I don't go over the taskbar area (which then you need to click on the arrow to see the hidden icons). If the icons were without labels then i can much more space down there for all the icons of the apps i have open to show up.

Is there a Reg setting for this, or an alternative app like Display Fusion, windhawk.net, some 'Taskbar Tweaker' app, etc to help with this exact 'Never combine but don't show Labels' setting?

Thanks!,
Arian

Comment: The option did not go away here. Unfortunately I cannot go back to show this. Did you make other registry changes causing this issue for you?

Comment: I didnt make any reg changes. Wondering if its group policy that removes this option or if we aren't on same versions of Windows11 (corporate IT keeps us behind the main updates sometimes).
I'm on this version of windows:
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise
Version: 10.0.22621 Build 22621
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version:  "10.0.22621.2506"

Comment: I miss this functionality too. I hate the grouping because it means I can't click the icon to minimize the program. But the labels are too long and it takes too much space :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my Win11 23H2: [Windhawk - Disable Grouping](https://windhawk.net/mods/taskbar-grouping)

First put the native Win11 Taskbar "Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels" setting to "Always" and then use this Windhawk extension to disable grouping.

Just have to say what a silly little gap msft has left us with... from web searching one can readily see many want this option.